# Is there a specific term for the genocide of children?

Tags: terminology, genocide

Let us suppose, hypothetically, a state engaged in the crime of genocide deliberately and disproportionately targets children for slaughter. Does this act have a particular designation in international law or even in e.g., scholarly work?

There are interestingly terms for this when referring to [gender-based genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gendercide) but I have not been able to find any for children.

Comment: I don't know that such a term is even logically consistent. Killing lots of children (the story of Herod's massacre of the innocents in the Bible is an example) and killing everyone in an ethnicity, are just very different, not really overlapping, concepts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacre_of_the_Innocents See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infanticide

Comment: One imagines that this question is motivated by the actions of Israel, which [has killed at least 10,000 children out of at least 27,000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93Hamas_war?wprov=sfla1) victims of its attacks in the Gaza Strip, around 37%. However, due to the demographics of the Gaza Strip, [over 40% of the population is under 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaza_Strip?wprov=sfla1). So if we agree that the Israeli attacks constitute genocide, the proper term for this would just be...genocide, which already encompasses the idea of killing everyone, children included.

Comment: "Genocide" is not the same thing as "killing".  That's the whole debate re Uyghurs for example.  Or for that matter, the - contentious - use of the term to refer to native-related problems in Canada.  So you could start up with reading the legal definition of the term & a dictionary.  Which brings to mind that maybe there is an ulterior motive to asking this.  Gendercide and femicide aren't inter-state or inter-ethnic phenomena so dont seem all that relevant except to cite some `cide` terms.

Comment: Killing children == killing children.  No more no less.  Which can be part of an overall genocide, true.  Why not ask on SE.English instead, if all you want is honest terminology lessons\?

Comment: Decent Q. I suppose the DV are because of Gaza, but the issue had been raised in Rwanda too: https://www.hrw.org/reports/2003/rwanda0403/rwanda0403-03.htm ; https://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/the-new-way-of-war-killing-the-kids

Comment: @fizz it's obviously a thinly-veiled push question.  The fact that the OP is trying to push the idea that this is happening is painstakingly obvious from their history, and even more so from their byline.

Comment: @RadicallyReasonable nothing in this question suggests that it is currently happening. Only Obie's comment and Fizz's comment suggest that.

Comment: The question is about semantics rather than politics - it is better asked in appropriate communities (linguistics, English, etc.) Note that suffix *-cide* generally means murder, but not a genocide, that is terms like *infanticide*, *fratricide* are not what the Q. is asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not about Politics (but semantics/languages.)

Answer (score -3):

There often aren't specific words that describe highly-specific situations that are only hypothetical.

Amongst all extant individuals in a population, children are the cheapest and quickest to replace, and typically have the least military utility.

Eliminating children actually releases more adults to be mobilised, who would otherwise have to be occupied with (and constrained by the needs of) child rearing, and releases the associated economic resources too.

I'm not aware of any case where children have been targeted preferentially for military destruction, since such preferential targeting implies that the adult population are being overlooked despite obviously posing the more serious and immediate military threat to any force which is attempting to destroy their children.

Even if the military purpose was to frustrate reproduction, sterilising or destroying the adult population - stopping children's lives coming into being in the first place - would typically be far more effective for any given commitment of military resources.

Comment: It's not hypothetical: "In 1994, on the eve of Rwanda’s genocide, Radio Mille Collines, in Kigali, incited listeners with a venomous message: “**To kill the big rats, you have to kill the little rats.**” It was a veiled command to murder the youngest generation of Tutsis, the country’s minority tribe." https://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/the-new-way-of-war-killing-the-kids

Comment: @Fizz, but is that about killing the kids in addition to killing the adults, or killing the kids *instead of* killing the adults (what the OP asked about)?

Comment: That seems to be your red herring. The OP wrote "disproportionately". It's not hard to see how that can come about, e.g. if male/adults are harder to get to. One point that seems to have happened in Rwanda is that women and children were easier to target, as the killings were often done by neighbors!

Comment: At least a term was invented for the latter: ["genocide of proximity"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22genocide+of+proximity%22).

Comment: @Fizz, I'm still admitting the possibility of adults being killed, but there has to be some kind of policy of killing children disproportionately surely, not just that children were coincidentally more accessible to kill when all people were candidates for slaughter. You seem to be saying that when the schoolhouse is closer on the war path than the barracks, there ought to be a special word, and a special categorisation of genocide, to reflect the coincidences of the situation which don't reflect any kind of special policy or strategic thinking.

Comment: @Fizz I suppose the answer is based implicitly on the example of Nazi concentration camps, where children and sick were indeed killed first, since they could not be used for work. One quarter of holocaust victims were children, though it seems that the age defining a *child* is set at 12 for this estimate, whereas nowadays using 18 is more commonplace.